# Explanation of why "Expected result to have changed by 1, but was changed by 0" error happens and what to do to fix it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec

I have a feature in which a user is able to add a new location, and i'm having a hard time adding a test to it.  (I'm horrible at testing, trying very hard to get better.)

I feel like I am very close to getting this test to work. The only error that I am running into right now is

`expected result to have changed by 1, but was changed by 0`

Now I don't know what i'm doing wrong.  I'm wondering if someone could help me with what would allow this test to pass, but also kind of an explanation of what is happening when this error happens. I'm really trying to become better a testing as its been something i've avoided and until recently accepted the importance of it, and had the courage to understand it.

Here is my spec file

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Admin::LocationsController, type: :controller do
  let(:admin) { FactoryGirl.create(:admin) }

  context 'super admin' do
    let!(:super_admin) { FactoryGirl.create(:super_admin) }

  before(:each) do
    sign_in(:user, super_admin)
  end

  describe '#create' do
    it 'creates a new location' do

      expect{
        post :create, location: {
          name: 'sample location',
          phone: '5555555555',
          fax: '5555555555',
          location_id: '123456',

          address_attributes: {
            address1: '12345 Some St',
            city: 'Portland',
            state: 'OR',
            zip: '91237'
          }
        }, format: :json

      }.to change {Location.count}.by(1)

      new_location = Location.last
      expect(new_location.name).to eq 'sample location'
      expect(new_location.phone).to eq '5555555555'
      expect(new_location.fax).to eq '5555555555'
      expect(new_location.location_id). to eq '123456'
      expect(new_location.address.address1).to eq '12345 Some St'
      expect(new_location.address.city).to eq 'Portland'
      expect(new_location.address.state).to eq 'OR'
      expect(new_location.address.zip).to eq '91237'
    end
  end
end
```

And here is my factory

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :location do |c|
    c.name 'sample location'
    c.phone '5555555555'
    c.fax '5555555555'
    location_id '123456'
    association :address, factory: :address
  end
end
```

Comment: It creates a new location. It creates a new location, but only admins are able to do it. I have a section in my app that only admins can see and that is where they are allowed to create a new location.

Comment: I should also say that in my controller, I have `inherit_resources` and so no official create method.

Comment: Is it possible that unique constraints prevent the location from being created?  If you're creating that elsewhere in your spec from the factory, then it's possible that using the same values in your post request would cause creation to fail if you have some kind of constraint.  Do you have any logs showing that the object is created when executing the test?

Comment: +1 for @JoeEssey's comment.  Are you sure the record is being created?  And what's the point of the Factory in this question?  You're not creating the location via factory?  In case you are in some other `before` scope you should make sure the name / phone / etc are DIFFERENT from what you're creating so you can be sure you're testing the values of the new record.

Comment: I would temporarily change the test to "0" and use the remaining expectations to verify if the record's created or not.

Comment: Ok guys, first off thank you very much for your wonderful comments, I deeply appreciate it.   I took @SteveTurczyn's advice and did a little debugging, and I can confidently say that the is not being created.  The Factory was in the app, and I thought it was useful with creating this test. (which likely proves my ignorance on this).

Comment: Well, good progress!  You'll probably want to "pry" in the controller's code to see why the record didn't get created... presumably because some validation(s) failed.  Good luck! :)